# Tortoise SVN Merge specific revision

Tags: svn, merge, version-control, tortoisesvn, release

I'm am starting to use SVN with client Tortoise.
Now I have the following situation:

I have my trunk at revision 20 and my branch is from revision 10.
I want to merge only a bug fix in revision 20.
In revision 20 I have 1 file change on test1.txt
In revision 19 I also had a change on test1.txt and on test2.txt.
The change in test1.txt from 19 uses something in the change in test2.txt.
The change in test1.txt from 20 uses something from the changes in 19.

When I just merge revision 20 I will have issues with my code changes.
So how can I see if I need to merge more revisions?

Is there an easier way then doing a "Show log" on each individual file in order to check?

I really don't want to merge all revisions between my trunk and branch.
Only the one's I need for specific bug fixes.

**Branch and Release tactics**

Right now we have a sprint of 6 weeks where all developers commit on the trunk continuously bug fixes/new functionality/clean ups etc.
After the 6 weeks we do a Branch split which will now have maybe like an additional 200 revisions when you compare it to the previous Branch.

After the branch is done all must be technical and functional tested.
This may result in rejections of issues, because of new bugs are introduced or other things. Before we can release the software to our customers we need all new issues to be approved.
So some issues will go back to developers and they will fix it in the trunk.
After all rejected issues are solved they need to be merged to the branch so it can be released to our customers.

Now you can say why don't you do the additional bug fixing in the branch itself. We used to do this but we sometimes had issues where it's fixed in the branch but forgot to merge to the trunk. So in the next branch the bug is back again.

Also it is very important that all developers can commit everything continuously without any hold ups. That's why all developers only work inside the trunk.

Comment: Okay so your branch of the trunk is at revision 10 where the trunk has moved forward and at revision 20, correct? You stated that the changes in revision 20 of the trunk uses the changes from changes 19. Why wouldn't you want all of the changes to keep yourself up to date? The idea of the branches in the first place is to work on a specific feature/bug/etc and then merge it _back_ into the trunk; so ideally you'd want to keep yourself up to date. What do you mean by how can you see if you need to merge more revisions? That's really a case by case basis to be honest.

Comment: Also, you can do a Show log on the entire checkout folder, not just the individual file.

Answer (score 4):

The comments I left are for clarification purposes. But to answer the *original* question of how to merge specific revisions, what you're going to want to do is:

1. Right click on your checkout folder > **TortoiseSVN > Merge...**.
2. Then you'll select `Merge a range of revisions`
3. Enter the URL to the trunk and select the option that says
   `specific range`. In the dialog you will then put the comma
   separated list of revisions you'd like to merge. (i.e. `19,20`) OR use the "Show log" feature and click on the revisions numbers you would want to merge.
4. Click **Next** > **Merge**

That will then merge the revisions you're looking for.

---

If you add some clarifications to my comments, I can extend my answer for you.

Comment: The problem is that there are multiple users committing and a file can have several revisions from different users. When we decide to merge a bug fix we don't know if it uses any other changes that have since been committed. So in my example we want to merge 20 but it also needs 19. But SVN does not know this.

Comment: The solution for you (for future merges) is probably to get good practices as first performing "atomic" commits related to only one bug fix, secondly indicating the bug reference in the log message. Thus you will be able to select easily through TortoiseSVN interface which revisions to merge for any bug fix to report, without (too many) conflicts.

Comment: I've updated my question with some of our branch/release tactics. This can maybe clarify things.

Comment: Upvoted for the efforts of explaining how to use SVN.